# Incrementally add to a file produced by an RDD

Tags: java, apache-spark, rdd

In Java I have a two dimensional array representing pixels in an image. Due to the size of the array (9744×9744) I can't keep the entire array in one RDD. I decided to process half of one row of the image at a time, and then output that into a file using `saveAsTextFile()`. When I do this I get `Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileAlreadyExistsException` after the first row is processed.

Is there a way to incrementally add to the file produced by the first half of the first row RDD? Below is an example of what I am trying to do.

```
    int pixs[][] = new int[4872][2];
    int count = 0;
    int rowI = 0;
    int colJ = 0;
    int colJCurrent = 0;
    JavaRDD<int[]> firstHalf = null;
    sparkPixels = new double[ 1 ][ 9744 ][3];

    for( ; rowI < 1; rowI++ )
    {       
        for(int colCount=0;colCount < 2;colCount++)
        {
            for( colJ=colJCurrent; colJ < (colJCurrent+(rawWidth)); colJ++ )
            {
                pixs[count][0]=rowI;
                pixs[count][1]=colJ;
                count++;
            }
            colJCurrent=colJ;
            count=0;

                firstHalf = ctx.parallelize(Arrays.asList(pixs));
                JavaRDD<SimpleMatrix> firstResults = firstHalf.map(new Function<int[], SimpleMatrix>() {
                    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                    public SimpleMatrix call(int pix[])
                    {
                        return PixelInfoFunction(pix[0], pix[1]);
                    }
                });

                JavaRDD<String> stringOutput = firstResults.map(new Function<SimpleMatrix, String>() {
                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                public String call(SimpleMatrix i)
                {
                    return PixelInfoInStringFormatt;
                }
            });

            stringOutput.saveAsTextFile("/home/bielasjj/Projection_Output/test");   
        }
        colJ=0;
        count = 0;
        colJCurrent=0;

    }

    ctx.stop();
    ctx.close();
```

I have modified the code to process one line at a time and add that to an array for later output, but at run time I get an `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded`

```
for(int rowI = 0 ; rowI < 9744; rowI++ )
    {
        for(int colJ = 0 ; colJ < 9744; colJ++ )
        {
            pixs[colJ][0]=rowI;
            pixs[colJ][1]=colJ;
        }

        JavaRDD<int[]> firstHalf = ctx.parallelize(Arrays.asList(pixs));
        JavaRDD<SimpleMatrix> rowResults = firstHalf.map(new Function<int[], SimpleMatrix>() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            public SimpleMatrix call(int pix[])
            {
                return PixelInfoFunction(pix[0], pix[1]);
            }
        });

        rowResults.foreach(new VoidFunction<SimpleMatrix>(){
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            public void call(SimpleMatrix i)
            {
                sparkPixels[(int)i.get(3,0)][(int)i.get(4,0)][0] = i.get(0, 0);
                sparkPixels[(int)i.get(3,0)][(int)i.get(4,0)][1] = i.get(1, 0);
                sparkPixels[(int)i.get(3,0)][(int)i.get(4,0)][2] = i.get(2, 0);
            }
        });

    }
    PrintWriter csv = new PrintWriter("/home/CSV.csv");
    for(int i=0; i < (2 * rawWidth)-1; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j < (3 * rawHeight)-1; j++)
        {
            String line = i+ "," + j + ", " + (int)sparkPixels[i][j][0] +", "+(int)sparkPixels[i][j][1]+", "+(int)sparkPixels[i][j][2];
            csv.println(line);
        }
    }
    csv.close();
```

Comment: _"Due to the size of the array 9744X9744 I can't keep the entire array in one RDD."_ What makes you think that? You can easily have an RDD of that size. You can have RDDs containing petabytes.

Comment: I modified the code to create one line at a time. How ever since I cannot incrementally add to the output file, I load each line into an `(9744X9744)` output array and use `java.io.File` to create an output file. When I run this code using 'spark-submit' I get `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded` or a heap error.

Answer (score 0):

Add the row number in the output file name:

```
stringOutput.saveAsTextFile("/home/bielasjj/Projection_Output/test" + rowI);
```

Comment: When the program gets to the second half of row 0 I still get the FileAlreadyExistsException. I was hoping to keep everything in one file if possible.